# Using openssl encryption for Apple's HTTP Live Streaming - problem

Tags: encryption, streaming, openssl, aes

This is my code of my shell script when `static.key` contains my random key.

```
hexKey=$(cat static.key | hexdump -e '16/1 "%02x"')
echo $hexKey
hexIV="0"
echo $hexIV
openssl aes-128-cbc -e -in logo-1.ts -out logo-enc-1.ts -p -nosalt -K ${he-iv ${hexIV}
```

I get some error when running it.

```
(output:
non-hex digit
invalid hex iv value
: command not found
)
```

Maybe someone knows the problem.  I'm on it for days now.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That error means that the value OpenSSL sees for the IV contains a non-hexadecimal character (i.e., something other than 0123456789abcdefABCDEF).

An AES128 key is `128/8 = 16` bytes, so you should have 32 characters for the key.  An IV is 16 bytes, corresponding to the AES block size, and OpenSSL will covert a single "0" into 16 zero bytes for you.  This is an example of a good command:

```
$ echo -n "hello" > in
$ openssl aes-128-cbc -e -in in -out out -p -nosalt \
  -K 000102030405060708090a0b0c0d0e0f -iv 000102030405060708090a0b0c0d0e0f
$ cat out | hexdump -e '16/1 "%02x"'
8326dc340c564d49790650a59260fea0
```

Now replace the last character of the IV with a non-hex character, and see that you get the same error you're getting.

```
$ openssl aes-128-cbc -e -in in -out out -p -nosalt \
  -K 000102030405060708090a0b0c0d0e0f -iv 000102030405060708090a0b0c0d0e0q
$ cat out | hexdump -e '16/1 "%02x"'
non-hex digit
invalid hex iv value
```

If what you've pasted is the real code you're running, the problem is obvious.  First, what is `-K ${he-iv ${hexIV}` supposed to mean?  Second, the argument `-K` is to give the key.  You're missing `-iv` to give the IV.  You're even missing a closing brace.

This will probably fix your problem assuming `static.key` has 16 bytes:

```
openssl aes-128-cbc -e -in logo-1.ts -out logo-enc-1.ts -p -nosalt -K $hexKey -iv $hexIV
```

As a last tip, if you're using bash, run your script with `-x` as the argument to bash and it will print every line it executes after it expands the variables so you can see exactly what it's doing:

```
$ /bin/bash -x my_script
+ hexKey=0
+ hexIV=0
+ openssl aes-128-cbc -e -in in -out out -p -nosalt -K 0 -iv 0
```

Answer (score 2):

In the process of storing the key value in the bash shell, some trailing garbage got included (either a null or newline) which is being passed to openssl and causing it to complain about non hex characters.

To fix this for 128 bit / 32 ascii character hex keys and IVs, tell bash to pass ONLY the first 32 characters like this (for other key or iv lengths change the value from 32 to 1/4 the number of bits in the key or iv)

```
openssl aes-128-cbc -e -in logo-1.ts -out logo-enc-1.ts -p -nosalt -K ${hexKey:0:32} -iv ${hexIV:0:32}
```

To verify that the correct values are being passed, use openssl's 'print keys' -P option (note UPPER CASE "-P")

```
openssl aes-128-cbc -e -in logo-1.ts -out logo-enc-1.ts -p -nosalt -K ${hexKey:0:32} -iv ${hexIV:0:32} -P
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been struggling with this, basically I found this solution:

Encrypt:

```
openssl aes-256-cbc -k “choose_password_to_encrypt” -in /path_to_your_file_to_encrypt/file_to_encrypt.extension_file -out /path_to_your_file_to_dencrypt/choose_name_file_after_decrypt.extension_file.enc -a
```

Decrypt:

```
openssl aes-256-cbc -k “password_chose_to_encrypt” -in /path_to_your_file_to_dencrypt/choose_name_file_after_decrypt.extension_file.enc -d -a -out /path_to_your_file_to_encrypt/file_to_encrypt.extension_file
```

I hope it can be useful